# Approximation of $x\log x$

Tags: asymptotics, approximation

I was wondering if anyone knows a good approximation for the function 
$$f(x)=x\log x $$
when $x$ goes to infinity. In particular, I would like to get rid of the $\log x$ and so I need a polynomial approximation. (I think Stirling would not work very well.)

Comment: You have me curious.  If you already have the function, why do you want to approximate it?  Also, have you tried a Taylor or Maclaurin series expansion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=a+t(b-a)$ for some $t$ in the range $0$ to $1$.  You get :

Let $c=b-a$

$$y = (a+ct)\log(a+ct)$$

$$y=(a+ct)\log\left( a\left(1+\frac c a t\right) \right)$$

$$y = (a+ct)\log(a) + (a+ct)\log\left(1+\frac c a t\right)$$

You can now replace the $\log()$ in the RHS by any suitable polynomial covering a reasonable range of values.

Note that using the arbitrary choice $a=c$ greatly simplifies things.

Good expressions for $\log(1+x)$ are possibly better chosen from [Páde approximants](http://www.nezumi.demon.co.uk/consult/logx.htm) than from ordinary polynomials. [This page](http://www.nezumi.demon.co.uk/consult/logx.htm) particularly mentions $\log(1+x)$ Páde expressions and nearer home [this Q&A on Mathematics SE describes exactly this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860293/how-to-compute-the-pade-approximation).

Answer (score 3):

There is no adequate polynomial or power law approximation.  For large $x$, $f(x)=x\log x$ grows more slowly than $x^{1+\epsilon}$ and more rapidly than $x^{1-\epsilon}$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Hey Buzz, thanks for the comment. I understand what you mean, but then, should I just say that there is no good approximation? My problem comes from the fact that I have an equation in which such terms appears, and I need to find x as a function of the rest; so what could I do? Just say that it is not possible to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

By the substitution $u=\frac{1}{x}$ you can convert this to approximating $g(u)=-\displaystyle{\frac{\ln(u)}{u}}$ for $u\to0$.  Then you can use the Taylor series for $g(u)$ centered at $u=1$, for example.