# Taylor series expansion of $x^x$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am well aware of the expansion by using $e^{x*ln{x}}$ and am looking for a different way. Can somebody please tell me a different expansion for $x^x$?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: If you substitute $x\ln{x}$ into the Taylor series for $e^x$, you don't get a Taylor series.  There are no $\ln{x}$ factors in a power series.  Also, Taylor series about what point?  Note that $x^x$ is not analytic at $x=0$, so it cannot be developed in a Taylor series about $x=0.$

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2322635/taylor-expansion-of-xx-at-x-0

Comment: You may want to consider using Pade Approximant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860293/how-to-compute-the-pade-approximation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is no Taylor series about $x=0$, you could expand about any positive $x$.  The series around $x=1$ is 
$$ 1+(x-1)+ \left( x-1 \right) ^{2}+{\frac{1}{2}} \left( x-1 \right) ^{3}+
{\frac{1}{3}} \left( x-1 \right) ^{4}+{\frac{1}{12}} \left( x-1
 \right) ^{5}+{\frac{3}{40}} \left( x-1 \right) ^{6}-{\frac{1}{120}}
 \left( x-1 \right) ^{7}+{\frac{59}{2520}} \left( x-1 \right) ^{8}-{
\frac{71}{5040}} \left( x-1 \right) ^{9}+ \ldots $$

See OEIS sequences [A082525](https://oeis.org/A082525), [A082526](https://oeis.org/A082526) and [A005727](https://oeis.org/A005727).

Comment: is it possible to use this to integrate x^x???

Comment: Term-by-term, yes.  There is no closed form though.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, you could also consider Padé approximants built around $x=1$ (just as for the Taylor series given in Robert Israel's answer).

Choosing the $[5,5]$ approximant and using $t=x-1$ for an easier legibility, we should get
$$x^x=\frac{1+\frac{129004 }{82639}t+\frac{166329 }{165278}t^2+\frac{250321
   }{578473}t^3+\frac{386677 }{3470838}t^4+\frac{1341953
   }{69416760}t^5 } {1+\frac{46365 }{82639}t-\frac{91679 }{165278}t^2-\frac{42594
   }{578473}t^3+\frac{436889 }{3470838}t^4-\frac{599629
   }{23138920}t^5 }$$ which is equivalent to a Taylor series to $O\left((x-1)^{11}\right)$.